# Citation signals in numbered references

Tags: citations, citation-style

I'm reformatting a manuscript from author-date referencing to Nature's (superscript) numbered referencing. How can I include [citation signals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citation_signal) such as 'e.g.,' or 'see'? For example, how should I reformat the following sentence?

> It was demonstrated that pigs can't fly (e.g., Smith, 1901).

I can omit the citation signal completely:

> It was demonstrated that pigs can't fly<sup>1</sup>.

but then important information about the non-exhaustiveness of the citation is lost.

Someone suggested this:

> It was demonstrated that pigs can't fly (e.g., <sup>1</sup>).

But it looks somewhat strange. Any idea?

Comment: What about "*Smith^1 demonstrated that pigs can't fly*", where the superscript 1 appears with "Smith"? (Comments apparently don't allow for either <sup>1</sup> or $^1$ formats, by the way.) Note this is also a more informative statement, since "It" is replaced by "Smith".

Comment: Do you really need the 'eg', 'see' etc?

Comment: @Fabio Dias, I find 'e.g.'  necessary when I cite only few examples instead of the entire list of  studies that substantiated a particular claim. You can't always cite everybody but it's important to convey that there are more studies out there. 'See' is more subtle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dislike this citation style for just this reason.

You can, however, get around it by turning the parenthetical citation into a phrase:

> A number of studies, including Smith<sup>1</sup>, have demonstrated that pigs can't fly.

More often, however, I see this being indicated implicitly by using more than one citation:

> A number of studies<sup>1-3</sup> have demonstrated that pigs can't fly.

Comment: I'll try the the 'Including Smith' phrase, it's a good idea. Do you feel that 'a number of studies' really conveys the message of the e.g. signal?

Comment: @Tal I think it's not a good way of saying "e.g.", but I also think I see people doing it.